# React Native: How to switch page without using NavigatorIOS component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm newbie for react js and react native, I'm wondering how to navigate from one page(component) to another page(component) without relying on navigatorIOS or navigator component? In Hybrid develop mode, it's so easy, just add html element A with href attribute would work, but in React Native, how to do it without using NavigatorIOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to create a function that renders the component you would like to show on a click, basically replicating the functionality of an href:

```
  changeComponent: function(component) {
    this.setState({
        componentSelected: component    
    })
  },

  renderComponent: function(component) {
        if(component == 'One') {
        return <ComponentOne changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
      } else if(component == 'Two') {
        return <ComponentTwo changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
      } else if(component == 'Three') {
        return <ComponentThree changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
      }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderComponent(this.state.componentSelected)}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And calling the function like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('Two') } style={styles.button}><Text>Two</Text></TouchableHighlight>
```

I Set up a full project [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/HbqJpA):

https://rnplay.org/apps/HbqJpA

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            componentSelected: 'One'
        }
    },

  changeComponent: function(component) {
    this.setState({
        componentSelected: component    
    })
  },

  renderComponent: function(component) {
        if(component == 'One') {
        return <ComponentOne changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
      } else if(component == 'Two') {
        return <ComponentTwo changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
      } else if(component == 'Three') {
        return <ComponentThree changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
      }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderComponent(this.state.componentSelected)}
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var ComponentOne = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', paddingTop:60, flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white', marginBottom:150, fontSize:20}}>Hello From Component One</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('Two') } style={styles.button}><Text>Two</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('Three') } style={styles.button}><Text>Three</Text></TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
})

var ComponentTwo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', paddingTop:60, flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white', marginBottom:150, fontSize:20}}>Hello From Component Two</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('One') } style={styles.button}><Text>One</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('Three') } style={styles.button}><Text>Three</Text></TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
})


var ComponentThree = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'purple', paddingTop:60, flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white', marginBottom:150, fontSize:20}}>Hello From Component Three</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('One') } style={styles.button}><Text>One</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('Two') } style={styles.button}><Text>Two</Text></TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
})

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  button: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ededed'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, relying on the setState to change component is what I did at the beginning, however, I still feel it's so inconvenient.  Here is an example:

Comment: Page 1 have two buttons, one to redirect to Page 1.a , the other will redirect to Page1.b,  and Page1.a has one button, this button should redirect to Page1.b, imagine if we have a deep page tree like that, then using setState and switch component would be so inconvenient and painful, I really doubt why react native doesn't have the function to just redirect to another Page :(

Comment: Most of that is covered in Navigator tbh, and yeah dealing with complex / nested states this way would be a huge pain lol!

Answer (score 1):

here's nader's code but updated to the latest version of react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  WebView,
  Dimensions,
  Modal,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

class test extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state =
    {
      componentSelected: 'One',
    }
  }

  changeComponent = (component) =>{
    this.setState({componentSelected: component});
  }

  renderComponent(component) {
        if(component == 'One') {
        return <ComponentOne changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
      } else if(component == 'Two') {
        return <ComponentTwo changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
      } else if(component == 'Three') {
        return <ComponentThree changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderComponent(this.state.componentSelected)}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class ComponentOne extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', paddingTop:60, flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white', marginBottom:150, fontSize:20}}>Hello From Component One</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('Two') } style={styles.button}><Text>Two</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('Three') } style={styles.button}><Text>Three</Text></TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class ComponentTwo extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', paddingTop:60, flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white', marginBottom:150, fontSize:20}}>Hello From Component Two</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('One') } style={styles.button}><Text>One</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('Three') } style={styles.button}><Text>Three</Text></TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}


class ComponentThree extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'purple', paddingTop:60, flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white', marginBottom:150, fontSize:20}}>Hello From Component Three</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('One') } style={styles.button}><Text>One</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.changeComponent('Two') } style={styles.button}><Text>Two</Text></TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  button: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ededed'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => test);
```