# The 'this' keyword in React Native refers to the great-grandchild of 'this' instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Ok, I realise this code is smelly but just bear with me for a moment.

I was playing around with [the code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184020/react-native-how-to-switch-page-without-using-navigatorios-component/39909314#39909314) and I have a strange situation wrt the `this` keyword.

In the code snippets that follow below, I want a button press in `TopBar` to trigger the `goose` method in `index.ios.js`, which it does.  However, inside `goose` `this` refers to the great grandchild:

Child = `ComponentOne`

Grandchild = `VoterScreen`

Great-Grandchild = `TopBar`

Clearly, this is due to the way I'm passing the `props` down to the `TopBar` which I'm certain isn't the 'React Native way' but can anybody tell me either:

1 - How to adapt the code below and refer to `this` correctly (from what I've read that would make `render` be called again because of a change in state, eliminating the need to call forceUpdate()).

OR:

2 - How to enable the great-grandchild to call a `goose` where `this` is the `this` I expect by editing the way the `callbacks` are working.

**The code for `index.ios.js`:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import VoterScreen from './components/voter-screen.js'

export default class StyleAB extends Component {
  constructor(props)
{
  super(props);
  this.state =
  {
    componentSelected: 'One',
  }
}

changeComponent = (component) =>{
  this.setState({componentSelected: component});
}

goose(){
  console.log('State before: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state));
  this.state = { componentSelected: 'Two', }
  console.log('State after: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state));
  this.forceUpdate();
}

renderComponent(component) {
      if(component == 'One') {
      return <ComponentOne changeComponent={this.changeComponent} goose={this.goose} />
    } else if(component == 'Two') {
      return <ComponentTwo changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
    } else if(component == 'Three') {
      return <ComponentThree changeComponent={this.changeComponent} />
    }
}

render() {
  console.log('Render is called');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.renderComponent(this.state.componentSelected)}
    </View>
  );
}
}

class ComponentOne extends Component {
  render() {
return (
  <VoterScreen sendData={this.props.goose}/>
)
  }
}

class ComponentTwo extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <UploadScreen/>
)
  }
}

class ComponentThree extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <ResultsScreen/>
)
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
flex: 1,
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('StyleAB', () => StyleAB);
```

**The code for `voter-screen.js`:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import TopBar from './top-bar.js'

class VoterScreen extends Component {
  render() {
console.log('Render is called in VoterScreen');
let topIsA = true;
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <TopBar parentToggle={this.props.sendData}/>
    </View>
  );
  }

}

export default VoterScreen
```

**The code for `top-bar.js`:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

class TopBar extends Component {

  render() {
console.log('Render is called in TopBar');
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
    <Button
    raised
    containerViewStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}
    icon={{name: 'camera', type: 'font-awesome', size: 20, style: {marginRight: 0, textAlign: 'center'}}}
    buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: '#cd00cd', borderRadius: 10, width: 50, height: 50}}
    onPress={this.props.parentToggle.bind(this)}
    />
  </View>
)
 }

}

export default TopBar
```

**EDIT:
The answer was to do 3 things:**

1 - In `index.ios.js`:

Change:

`return <ComponentOne changeComponent={this.changeComponent} goose={this.goose} />`

To:

`return <ComponentOne changeComponent={this.changeComponent} goose={this.goose.bind(this)} />`

2 - in the same file:

Change:

`<VoterScreen sendData={this.props.goose}/>`

To:

`<VoterScreen sendData={this.props.goose.bind(this)}/>` [Thanks Chris].

3 - In `top-bar.js`:

Change:

`onPress={this.props.parentToggle.bind(this)}`

To:

`onPress={this.props.parentToggle}`  [Thanks Eduard].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding the scope before passing it down like this...

```
<VoterScreen sendData={this.props.goose.bind(this)}/>
```

Comment: Yep, that approach should work, now `this` refers to the `VoterScreen` so I guess doing something similar again will get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks.  Combining your answer with Eduard's and a adding `.bind(this)` to `goose={this.goose` making `goose={this.goose.bind(this)` did the trick.  I will mark your answer as correct since you answered first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `this` to refer to the parent component, why do you bind it in the great grandchild?
Have you tried going this way?

```
onPress={this.props.parentToggle}
```

or this:

```
onPress={() => this.props.parentToggle}
```

Comment: Thanks. Both ways you suggest have the same effect as Chris's answer and gets me one step closer.

Comment: Thanks.  Combining your answer with Chris's and a adding `.bind(this)` to `goose={this.goose` making `goose={this.goose.bind(this)` did the trick.  I will mark his answer as correct since he answered first but thank you.

Comment: @DaveChambers glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I read what you're asking correctly but changing `goose(){` to `goose = () => {` should fix all your issues. Also it's not good for performance to bind in render so you might want to create another method on each component you want to bind or bind in the constructor.